# Issue with responsive view on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am not sure if i am asking the question in the right place, but from many days i have been facing an issue with my Magento theme and tried fixing it by editing the layout. but i am not able to get it right for my product page on the responsive side.

The product page hides the Add to cart option behind the header when browsed from mobile or Tablets.

On web it looks like it is working absolutely fine.
Is there anyone who can guide me on where to look into for fixing the issue.

www.omegakart.com is the website that i am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick workaround correct your CSS `local.css` in line 2,005. The `float: none` prevents your `<div class="product-img-box>` from floating after your product details including your 'Add to card' instead of overlaying it.
That's just a quick hint, but as I'm sure this is **not** the right place to ask design/layout questions like yours and as you are using a template for your store, please contact your template provider to get that fixed. There seems alot to be mixed up...

Comment: Thank you for the quick input, the provider of the template is off grid and i not sure how to get help from him, for now the pointer was a good direction to look into and i have somehow fixed the overlaying issue. I am not stuck with a issue where the 'product-shop' is stuck outside the margin and i am trying to figure out what would be solution for that. If you see the page in responsive for mobiles the grids are falling in place like it has to but the add to cart is not accessable now. http://www.omegakart.com/apparels/women/clothing/dresses-skirts/siya-parineeti-2002.html

Comment: Well, can you explain how you test your responsive layout? I don't have that effect when debugging with Chrome's mobile viewport tool.